# How to use two xpath inside xpath contains function

Tags: xml, xpath

I have one dropdown box like so:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="dropdownlist">

<select name="childVariationASIN" style="width:180px;"> 


<option value="" selected="selected" title="Select">Select</option>
<option value="B002VYJB5S" title="59 mm :: 101/13 Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient">Gold-Cre...</option> 
<option value="B00193CBMM" title="59 mm :: 103/11 Gunmetal-Grey/Grey Gradient">Gunmetal...</option> 
<option value="B003ENRWHE" title="59 mm :: 103/13 Gunmetal-Grey/Brown">Gunmetal...</option> 

</select>
</div>
<div id='selected_product_name'>
Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient
<div>


</body>
</html>
```

And have another div which displays product names, e.g. "Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient".

Now I need to get the option value="B002VYJB5S" by defining XPath expression which checks that product name div against the option title attribute. Something like this:

```
<xpath expression="//select[@name='childVariationASIN']/option[@value!='' and @title[contains(//div[@id='selected_product_name']/text()) " >
```

This "contains" part dosen't work. How can I get that corresponding option value "B002VYJB5S"?

and i am not sure about that xpath expression is correct one

Thanks 
Ram

Comment: Is the space between `@` and `name` a typo?

Comment: thats my typo here only. that contains function only not working orelse u can suggest diff xpath expression to get that desired option value. please feel free to ask any clarification. Thanks

Comment: @user659956: I have now produced the final solution and also provided extensive explanation.

Comment: @user659956: So, did you try to use my solution?

Answer (score 3):

> Something like this:
>
> ```
> <xpath expression=
> "//select[@ name='childVariationASIN']
>           /option[@value!='' 
>                 and 
>                  @title[contains(.,//div[@id='selected_product_name']/text())
>
> " >
> ```
>
> This "contains" part dosen't work.

**Without showing us the XML document against which the XPath expression is evaluated, we can only try to guess the reason**...

**It is likely that**

`//div[@id='selected_product_name']/text()`

selects more than one text nodes (such as white-space-only text nodes) and the wanted text node doesn't happen to be the first.

Or, that the wanted text node is not a child of the `div`, but just its descendent.

Or, ...

**UPDATE**: The OP has now showed us the XML document.

We happily and instantaneously find the problem and fix the XPath expression:

```
//select[@ name='childVariationASIN']
   /option[@value!=''
          and
           @title
             [contains(.,normalize-space(//div[@id
                                              =
                                              'selected_product_name'
                                              ]
                                              /text()
                                              )
                       )
              ]
          ]
```

**If you don't believe this expression selects the wanted node, here is a simple verification to try:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  " //select[@ name='childVariationASIN']
       /option[@value!=''
              and
               @title
                 [contains(.,normalize-space(//div[@id
                                                  =
                                                  'selected_product_name'
                                                  ]
                                                  /text()
                                             )
                           )
                  ]
             ]
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied against the provided XML document**:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="dropdownlist">
            <select name="childVariationASIN" style="width:180px;">
                <option value="" selected="selected" title="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="B002VYJB5S" title="59 mm :: 101/13 Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient">Gold-Cre...</option>
                <option value="B00193CBMM" title="59 mm :: 103/11 Gunmetal-Grey/Grey Gradient">Gunmetal...</option>
                <option value="B003ENRWHE" title="59 mm :: 103/13 Gunmetal-Grey/Brown">Gunmetal...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id='selected_product_name'> 
               Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient 
             </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<option value="B002VYJB5S" 
   title="59 mm :: 101/13 Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient">Gold-Cre...</option>
```

**Explanation**:

The text node child of the `div` element that we want our selected node to contain is:

```
<div id='selected_product_name'> 
Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient 
</div>
```

The text is:

```
" 
Gold-Cream/Brown Gradient 
"
```

It obviously contains a starting and ending NL characters -- but they are not contained in the `title` attribute of the `option` element that we want to select.

The standard XPath function `normalize-space()`, among other things, removes all starting and ending whitespace from a string -- we use it and its result is really contained in the `title` attribute of the `option` element.

Comment: Hi Dimitre i have edited the html part in original question now u can write your own xpath to get that value bcoz i am not sure abt my xpath expression is right one.

Comment: +1 Correct answer and extend explanation. I would drop the final text node selection and just use the string value.